# How to fix a levelled flooring to a sloped flooring

Tags: flooring

I currently have a large open air terrace that has been tiled without a slope for the drain.  When the contractors layed the concrete flooring they did not add a slope to allow for drainage and tiled on top of the concrete floor.  How do I rectify this to allow for a slope to where the water needs to drain.  Currently water is gathering when it rains and does not drain.

Comment: What sort of size is this?  Where do you want the water to drain to?

Comment: Retile with a slope towards the drain.